# Memoralize a Facebook account after deactivation

Tags: facebook

My partner recently died and his wife deactivated his Facebook account without informing his family.

Is there a way to memoralize his account?

Answer (score 7):

I’m really sorry for your loss.

I’m afraid it seems not, assuming wives count as immediate family members:

> Immediate family members may request the removal of a loved one’s account. This will completely remove the account from Facebook so that no one can view it. We will not restore the account or provide information on its content unless required by law.
>
> http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=13941&ref_query=memor

That help page has a link for special requests relating to memoralizing accounts, so it might be worth contacting Facebook on that to see if they can assist.